# Modifying a Makefile with "addinclude unistd"

Tags: c++, c, makefile, raspberry-pi

So I am attempting to compile a C program on my Raspberry Pi, and the instructions tell me to "addinclude uninstd" followed by the exact code:
`sed -i 's | #include <arpa / inet.h> | #include <arpa / inet.h> n #include <unistd.h> | g 'openmilight.cpp`

So, I believe the instructions are saying to modify the makefile, but what exactly do I put in the Makefile to include these libraries?

Here is the entire Makefile currently:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LIBS = -lrf24-bcm
SOURCES =  PL1167_nRF24.cpp MiLightRadio.cpp openmilight.cpp
BIN = openmilight

all: $(SOURCES) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
      rm -f *.o $(BIN)
```

Thank you, I am only vaguely familiar with working with Makefiles and this is confusing me like none other.

If it helps, here is the exact code I am attempting to run:
http://torsten-traenkner.de/wissen/smarthome/openmilight.php
It is in german, which may be why it is being lost in translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction is a sed command to modify the file `openmilight.cpp`. Nothing to do with makefiles.

Just execute the bash command in the directory of `openmilight.cpp` or add the inclusion by hand: open `openmilight.cpp` in your [preferred](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor and add the line

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

just after

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: Ohhh okay sed is a bash command. Thank you so much, that one was throwing me off for a while, based on some of the wording from his previous file I thought it was to modify the makefile by hand.